# Why my Dockerfile isn't executing commands

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to dockerise my Laravel app.

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1.14-fpm

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /tmp

RUN touch /app/resources/assets/less/_main_full/main.less \
&& touch /app/database.sqlite \
&& apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git npm \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng12-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
    sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev \
&& apt-get purge --auto-remove -y g++ \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring zip -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt -j$(nproc) gd \
&& curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash \
&& export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm" \
&& [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm \
&& nvm install node \
&& npm cache clean -f && npm install -g n && n stable && npm install cross-env && npm install && npm run dev \
&& curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
&& composer install --no-interaction \
&& chown -R www-data:www-data \
        /app/storage \
        /app/bootstrap/cache \
&&  chmod 755 /tmp/entrypoint.sh

CMD ["/tmp/entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I build it with:

```
docker build -f laravel-local.dockerfile . --no-cache
```

I get this output:

```
...
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
Removing intermediate container 642a7d7f4a59
 ---> 5121a6997e87
Step 6/6 : CMD ["/tmp/entrypoint.sh"]
 ---> Running in 7f7468684e00
Removing intermediate container 7f7468684e00
 ---> df2ee7652870
Successfully built df2ee7652870
```

I don't understand why isn't it executing all the composer and chown instructions

Comment: Try breaking up them cmds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance,

`# This loads nvm \` will comment out `\` so the subsequent cmds wont run.

Comment: Yep, writing the post made me see it :)

Comment: Id definatly break up them cmds though, as its just too much.

Comment: with more RUN won't it create extra layers that will increase image size ?

Comment: yup, but readability counts too, and besides - it should be extracted in parallel, reducing pull times (and you gave one answer to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69941011/why-is-docker-pull-not-extracting-layers-in-parallel)

Comment: 1 RUN is ideal (though OP should clean up apt at the end), the original issue was the comment line which is commenting out the trailing `\\`